# Dart's runZoned() behaviour on async modified bodies

Tags: asynchronous, dart

I don't get this behaviour...

```
main(args) async {
  await runZoned(() {
    throw false;
  }, onError: (e) async {
    print("working in onError");
    await runZoned(() {
      throw false;
    }, onError: (e) async {
      print("error 1");
    });
    print("error 2");
  });
  print("finish");
}
```

> working in onError
>
> error 1
>
> error 2
>
> finish

```
main(args) async {
  await runZoned(() async {
    throw await Future.error(false);
  }, onError: (e) async {
    print("working in onError");
    await await runZoned(() async {
      throw await Future.error(false);
    }, onError: (e) async {
      print("error 1");
    });
    print("error 2");
  });
  print("finish");
}
```

> working in onError
>
> error 1

those async on runZoned() change the behaviour radically, are they supposed to do so?

I need those asyncs and reaching the `print("finish")` always. How do I tackle the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [Irn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2156621/lrn) answer I understood and used a [Completer](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.5.2/dart-async/Completer-class.html) for achieving my goal:

```
main(args) async {
  var completer = Completer();
  await runZoned(() {
    Future.microtask((){
      throw Future.error(false);
    });
    completer.complete();
  }, onError: (e) {
    // ...
    completer.complete();
  });
  print("finish");
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You are hitting a sharp edge of futures and error(-handling) zones.

An error thrown in one error zone will not propagate to a future error handler created in another error zone.
So, if you get a future from a different error zone, and it has completed with an error, then you can't get the error, and there is no value to get, so the future will look like it *never* completes.

The code

```
main(args) async {
  await runZoned(() async {
    await Future.error(false);
  }, onError: (e) async {
    print("working in onError");
    await runZoned(() async {
      await Future.error(false);
    }, onError: (e) async {
      print("error 1");
    });
    print("error 2");
  });
  print("finish");
}
```

runs the arguments to `runZone` in new error zones. They're async functions returning futures, so the the `await Future.error(false)` will throw and complete the returned future with an error in that particular error zone.

Then, when the `runZoned` completes, it returns that future with an error created in a different error zone than the call. It is `await`ed (in the root zone, which is a different error zone) so `await runZoned(() async { ... }, ...)` *never completes*. The `await` waits for the future to complete, the future refuses to give the error that it completed with to the listener, so nothing happens.

You are, effectively, waiting on a future which never completes, which is why your program stops at that point.

So this is working as intended - the error never leaves the error zone it was created in, but that leaves the outer zone without any result.

The first example works because you are throwing synchronously, and not returning a future. The synchronous throw is caught immediately, and then the `runZoned` returns `null`. (That will have to change when Dart gets non-nullable types, though).

In general, it's probably a bad idea to return futures that can contain errors from a `runZoned` with an `onError` handler. We can't prevent that (returning `Object` is fine and futures are objects), but it should perhaps be documented.